# How do I display my json result in html using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

Using jQuery ajax I am obtaining a json result which I am trying to display in a paragraph element with the id `txtResult` using jQuery. Here is the .done section of my ajax call

```
     .done(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        console.log(result);

        if (result.status.name == "ok") {
            $('#txtResult').html(result['data']);
        }
    })
```

and here is the json result as displayed in the console:

```
    data:
       countryCode: "IT"
       countryName: "Italy"
       distance: "0"
       languages: "it-IT,de-IT,fr-IT,sc,ca,co,sl"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    status:
       code: "200"
       description: "success"
       name: "ok"
       returnedIn: "120 ms"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

﻿
​I am obviously doing something wrong as, although the result is displayed in the console, nothing appears on the page. Can anyone set me straight?

Comment: It seems like `result['data']` is an object with many properties. You need to specify which  properties you want display. `$('#txtResult').val(result.data.countryName)` for example. Also notice I am using `.val()` function, instead of `.html()`.

Comment: Given the prefix `txt` it's likely it's a textbox `<input type='text'` so you need `.val(..)` - include the html for your `txtResult` for confirmation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above, I found that

```
    $('#txtResult').html(result.data.countryCode);
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSON.stringify to conver json object to string

```
var str = JSON.stringify(result.data).replace(/",\"/gi, "<br />").replace(/"/gi, "").replace(/{/gi, "").replace(/}/gi, "") ;
$('#txtResult').html(str);
```

output

```
countryCode:IT
countryName:Italy
distance:0
languages:it-IT,de-IT,fr-IT,sc,ca,co,sl
```